# xmpp with python: xmpp.protocol.InvalidFrom: (u'invalid-from', '')

Tags: python, xmpp, bots

```
cl = xmpp.Client('myserver.com')
if not cl.connect(server=('mysefver.com',5223)):
    raise IOError('cannot connect to server')
cl.RegisterHandler('message',messageHandler)
cl.auth('myemail@myserver.com', 'mypassword', 'statusbot')
cl.sendInitPresence()

msgtext = formatToDo(cal, 'text')
message = xmpp.Message('anotheremail@myserver.com',  msgtext) 
message.setAttr('type', 'chat')
cl.send(message)
```

I get the following error message when I try to run it:

```
xmpp.protocol.InvalidFrom: (u'invalid-from', '')
```

Why is this happening :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the XMPP protocol [specification](http://www.isi.edu/in-notes/rfc3920.txt):

> If the value of the 'from'
>   address does not match the hostname represented by the Receiving
>   Server when opening the TCP connection (or any validated domain
>   thereof, such as a validated subdomain of the Receiving Server's
>   hostname or another validated domain hosted by the Receiving Server),
>   then the Authoritative Server MUST generate an  stream
>   error condition and terminate both the XML stream and the underlying
>   TCP connection.

which basically means, that if the sender is not recognized by the xmpp-server, it'll reply with this message. XMPP supplies a registration mechanism: [xmpp.features.register](http://xmpppy.sourceforge.net/apidocs/xmpp.features-module.html#register)